# Mysql error - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now - postman error - codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My application is in codeigniter framework , in my application I written a rest api function. When I call that function from postman i got an error:

ERROR:  Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Firstly I call a model function for invoking a stored procedure and then i calls a normal query .The provided codes are representational purpose only.

My API function is :(All are dummy functions)

```
 public function products_get()
{
  
    $cat_id = $this->input->get('cat_id');
     
   $sub_categories = $this->Products_model->fetch_cate($cat_id); //dummy functions
    
    $products = $this->Products_model->get_pdts($cat_id);
  
  
    $data['status'] = TRUE;
    $data['message'] = 'success';
    $data['categories'] = $products;
    $this->set_response($data, self::HTTP_OK);
}
```

My model function is:

```
public function fetch_cate($cat_id)
{
    
    $query = $this->db->query("CALL getSubcategory($cat_id)");
    return $query->result();

}

 public function get_pdts()
{

   return $this->db->get('category_product')->result();
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I find a decent solution from internet just posting after this question :

Add this line of code  ->

```
mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id );
```

After the stored procedure call ->

```
    $query = $this->db->query("CALL getSubcategory($cat_id)");
    mysqli_next_result( $this->db->conn_id ); //add this line of code
```